# Webpack при сборке меняет ссылку на запрос и подставляет часть адреса

Tags: javascript, webpack, react-router, build, create-react-app

Я столкнулся с проблемой при сборке. Если открыть на локалхосте, все работает отлично, но если делаю сборку, то у меня не загружаются картинки. Возможно проблема возникла из-за настройки webpack, в jsconfig только вот это добавил:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "src"
},
"include": ["src"]
```

}

Я использую axios, в конфигурации прописан только baseURL.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это у вас не webpack меняет, это вы забыли как относительные ссылки работают...

Comment: Там была проблема в том, что я прописал homepage: '.' в package.json. А можешь подсказать, почему у меня минус на вопросе стоит? )))

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Помогло удаление homepage из package.json